# Aristotle's Categories and Linguistics

Tags: aristotle, philosophy-of-logic, linguistics

I have actually two questions:

1. What he calls substances or non-substances seem to me as, now what we call a matter of language. So what he calls substances could be seen as concrete nouns, and non-Substances could be seen as abstract ones, or it can be said that what he calls things (nouns in particular) that are non-Substances are uncountables and Substances are countables. Is this the exact point, or is there an explanation, regarding linguistics, that can give a better acount of what it is?
2. Things that are *not* said of, and also that are *non*-Substances seems to me problematic, since what he calls *non*-Substances are seem to be **abstract** nouns, and there's always a sub-category of any particular abstact noun, because any individual abstract noun can be said to be infinitesimally small, so any category is actually a super category, thus any non-Substance **can** be said of a thing.

Comment: Just as reference which part of Aristotle are you reading? Providing that will make sure anyone who tries to answer this does not have to look for the source and is reading what most concerns your question. Welcome!

Comment: The language of A's *Categories* is not always easy to understand... We may imagine two oppositions : universal-particular and substance-accident. This gives rise to a fourfold schema : if so, what are "particular accidents" vs "universsl accidents" ? We may imagine to compare "this white" vs "whiteness".